# Push New VC from Subview Table View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistackview

I have an Arranged Subview (a Table View) within a parent View Controller.

Let's call the parent VC CollectionViewController and the subview (Table VC) ResultsTableViewController.

I've added the table view to my stackview (in CollectionViewController) like this:

```
let hitsTableController = ResultsTableViewController()
 
stackView.addArrangedSubview(hitsTableController.tableView)
```

Then I've implemented didSelectRowAt in the ResultsTableViewController (the subview):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
     let hit = hitsSource?.hit(atIndex: indexPath.row)
           
     print("The ID is " + hit?.id)
    
    
     let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ItemDetailViewController") as? ItemDetailViewController
        
      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
               }
    
}
```

I'm able to print information about the cell I select (the ID in this case), but I can't figure out how to navigate to the Details View Controller when a cell is pressed.

I've tried this with no luck:

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ItemDetailViewController") as? ItemDetailViewController
    
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

The code runs, but nothing happens. Any help would be appreciated.

**SOLUTION**

Add this

```
addChild(hitsTableController)
hitsTableController.didMove(toParent: self)
```

before this

```
stackView.addArrangedSubview(hitsTableController.tableView)
```

As Frankenstein mentioned below, the problem was that ResultsTableViewController had no access to the navigation stack. That's because I had to make it a child of the parent VC, CollectionViewController. Now I'm able to call this without any problems.

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

Comment: Are you building your UI programmatically or are you using storyboards? The above code looks like a mix of both.

Comment: Using both, because I'm using Algolia's InstantSearch for iOS. They only have a programmatic option.

Answer (score 0):

try to force unwrap your objects if the app crash then give us the crash details

```
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ItemDetailViewController") as! ItemDetailViewController    
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: Crash and error message: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file.

Comment: so which is it?

Comment: The app crashed for this one.

Comment: So it was related to Storyboard; I had to point to the "Main" storyboard and use present instead of push. Still working on the nav working properly, though.

Answer (score 0):

Update: With the details that you've added it has become evident that the issue was that the view controller isn't embedded in a `UINavigationController`. You see that `navigationController` is an optional and it get allocated only if the controller is embedded in a `UINavigationController`. Try this:

```
let hitsTableController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ResultsTableViewController())
stackView.addArrangedSubview(hitsTableController.tableView)
```

Seems the storyboard either has no `ItemDetailViewController` in it or you've forgotten to set the identifier which seems unlikely in your scenario. Hence I conclude that the `ItemDetailViewController` is created programmatically. So you should be initializing `ItemDetailViewController` with the empty initializer for presenting it.

```
let vc = ItemDetailViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: Didn't work, nothing happened. I've added some more details. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: That seems to cause problems with other components that interact with hitsTableController in CollectionViewController. Basically I've implemented [this (scroll to the bottom)](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-ios-examples/blob/d62d566ca1a458def4af15fce75b70526db18751/DemoDirectory/DemoDirectory/Views/HitView.swift) and I'm trying to add a didSelectRowAt, which isn't included in the demo; so I'm trying to extrapolate what to do.

Comment: I would agree that there definitely seems to be a problem with the Navigation Controller. Printing vc when I use your solution at least returns something; Navigation Controll returns nil. But I'm not sure if that's normal.

Comment: That would be normal in usual cases, but here you're trying to push a new vc to the nav controller so it must be embedded inside the nav vc. Did you try out the code that I have posted in the update?

Comment: I did; the problem with that is that I received error messages for other components, mainly this one : "Value of type 'UINavigationController' has no member 'tableView'".

Comment: That's because you are embedding the vc in nav vc so now you have to get tableview from the nav vc's root vc. It's a bit complicated but you'll surely understand what it means.

Comment: How do I do that?